# IntentService resume MainActivity on notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, google-api, android-pendingintent, resume

I use the GoogleTransitionIntentService to show a notification if a user enter a Geofence, but the notification recreate MainActivity.class. I want to resume this activity.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .setColor(Color.RED)
        .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
        .setContentText("Test")
        .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

builder.setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have an activity to Add Markers an a Google Map with Google API and to Start the Google Maps Navigation Intent to navigate to these markers. I want a notification that Resume the activity if a User Enter geofence around a Marker

Comment: make sure you are not calling finish() when u minimize the activity or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add flags like

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and set

```
android:launchMode =  "singleTop"
```

to activity in manifest.

From GoogleDoc

If the activity has launch mode singleTop (or the up intent contains FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), the parent is brought to the top of the stack, and its state is preserved. The intent is received by the activity's onNewIntent() method. If the activity has launch mode standard (and the up intent does not contain FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), the current activity and its parent are both popped off the stack, and a new instance of the parent activity is created to receive the navigation intent.

Comment: In Log the app called onCreate() after Notification clicked

Comment: Do one thing, let flag as it is and change launch mode to singleTask.. and set log in onNewIntent() of MainActivity.

Comment: Is onNewIntent() and Override Method? Not called without flags and launchMode:singleTask

Comment: Yes, you have to override because if activity is running then it will call onNewIntent instead of onCreate

Comment: no changes. onNewIntent never called after notification clicked

Answer (score 1):

You have to use launchmode as singleTop inside your menifest for the given activity.

```
android:launchMode =  "singleTop"
```

Comment: onCreate() called after notification clicked.

Comment: One AppCombatActivity (MainActivity) within 3 Fragments in a ViewPager

Comment: you need to add these inside mainactivity configs

Comment: your launch mode is  android:launchMode="singleTask"> change it to single top

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for MainActivity in the manifest.

Comment: onCreate() called after notification clicked.

Comment: Looks to me like you are finishing your activity somewhere when onPause is called. Try adding an override to onPause if you are not